# "Unable to load class" when starting Tomcat 7 web application

Tags: java, tomcat, catalina

I am recieving the below error message, whenever I deploy my application developed in Spring MVC:

```
Unable to load class [com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers

Java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
    ...
```

I have no idea what this means, other than the fact that a google class is final and something is trying to inherit it (which I am not doing anywhere in my code).  Any suggestions?

Comment: What sort of dependency management are you using (maven, ant, jars...)? Check if you got different dependencies on guava (might cause classloader problems). Check if the guava depenceny was deployed in your tomcat directory (tomcat deployment directory - aplpication - WEB-INF/lib).

Comment: I am using maven, it's not occurred to me that that the dependancy hierarchy could be the problem because of the comment regarding @handlesTypes - I'm not even sure what that annotation means.  I will have a check.

Comment: I dont think the @annotation is the reason for the tomcat exception. In my experiences the "Unable to load class" could have several reasons, also Eclipse WTP and maven messing up (eg. src/test/resources was deployed instead of src/main/resources). Sometimes this is really annoying to find. Have a look at the dependencies, deployed folders, update maven config/clean projects etc.